# iOS Float/Double without rounding

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Ok I had a pretty dumb question. I need to separate a float by two:

- First part to contain whole number part and two digits after decimal dot
- Second item should contain third and fourth digits from the float

The important thing is that I do not want any rounding(whether up or down). So pretty much the following:

```
12.8 => 12.80 && 00
12.8999999999 => 12.89 && 99
12.899999 => 12.89 && 99
12.0005 => 12.00 && 05
```

**The format string approach**

I need exactly 4 digits after decimal point no matter what, so I need to use %.4f or %f(and cut last two components) in order to handle 12.8 => 12.8000. However when the number has many 9's after decimal point auto-round-up is present:

```
let test = 122.899999999999
let sut = String(format: "%f", test) // 122.900000 instead of 122.899999
```

**Round approach**

I tried to use standard C floor method as it should round down my float. However if 9's after decimal point are way greater than my "divider" floor acts like a round:

```
let test = 122.89999999999999

let divider = 10000.0

let sut = (Double(floor(test * divider)) / divider) // 122.9 instead of 122.8999
```

So any advices are greatly welcomed :)

Comment: Floating points digits are not precise. Never. You can't expect precise results then. Use `NSDecimalNumber` for precise calculations.

Comment: I checked it, and it doesn't output 122.9, it outputs 122.8999. The code that you posted is not the code that you are running.

Comment: @Sulthan: double x = 1.5 is absolutely one hundred percent precise.

Comment: @gnasher729 Nope, not only "1.5" but an infinite number of decimal numbers will be encoded to the same binary representation.

Comment: Use appropriate NSFormatter

Comment: gnasher729 I double check in playground and it again says 122.9. Sultan could you provide an example with NSDecimalNumber doesn't matter swift or objc?

Comment: @Sulthan That doesn't mean 1.5 is not stored precisely. As well as e.g. any integer within 2^(mantissa_size+1)-10. Also, if you're rounding on each operation or otherwise keep erroneous bits far below your truncation level, float/double is just fine. Please do not scarify floating point too much, it is okay unless you try hard to accumulate the error.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use float, `float` is not precise. Use `NSDecimalNumber`. The `NSDecimalNumber` class provides fixed-point arithmetic capabilities. They’re designed to perform base-10 calculations without **loss of precision** and with predictable rounding behavior. This makes it a better choice for representing currency than floating-point data types like double. However, the trade-off is that they are more complicated to work with.

```
NSDecimalNumber *price1 = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithFloat:15.99f]] ;
NSDecimalNumber *price1 = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithFloat:29.99f]] ;
NSLog(@"Subtotal: %@", [price1 decimalNumberByAdding:price2]);
```

It will output 45.98.

[See this.](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsdecimalnumber)

**EDIT:**

Here is the apples documentation about [NSDecimalNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/index.html).

Comment: I don't have the number as String, I have it as a Double from web service and SwiftyJSON.

Comment: Your suggestion does not cover the original question. My problem is that while converting float/double to string I loose precision while you are suggesting to use decimalNumberWithString.

Comment: @hris.to > Did you see the documentation??

Comment: Again I had the numbers from web service, so I cannot control them and change to be Strings. They are coming as float/doubles after deserialization from JSON.

Comment: @hris.to> [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithFloat:15.99f]] ; did you see this in my answer?????

Comment: @Rashad, I try like this: NSDecimalNumber *price1 = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble:9.875]; NSLog(@"Subtotal: %@", price1); That is worked for me. Thank a lot.

Answer (score -2):

I believe this function does what you need:

```
func returnWhatINeed(number : Double) -> (fst : Double, snd : Int, trd : Int) {

  // get the number without any decimals
  let noDecimals = Double(Int(number))
  // get the decimals
  let decimals = number - noDecimals
  // get the first four decimals after the floating point
  var tempDecimals = Int(decimals * 10000)

  // get the fourth decimal
  let fourth = tempDecimals % 10
  tempDecimals /= 10
  // get the third decimal
  let third = tempDecimals % 10
  // get the first two decimals
  tempDecimals /= 10


  return (noDecimals + Double(tempDecimals) / 100, third, fourth)
}
```

Usage:

```
let result = returnWhatINeed(122.8479999999999)
```

`result.fst` will contain the floating point number with only the first two decimals : `122.84`

`result.snd` and `result.trd` will contain the third (`7`) and fourth (`9`) decimals

Note this is a quick solution to your problem. In the future you should use `NSNumberFormatter` to get the expected format.

Comment: If I try your solution with 122.66799999999999999999999 I get: 122.66, 8, 0 which is not correct

Comment: That is because 122.66799999999999999999999 is automatically converted to 122.668. Try using NSNumberFormatter instead.

Comment: Ok could you please provide an example with NSNumberFormatter?

Comment: I'm downvoting you because your solution does not cover the main problem with the rounding. Also you did not provide solution with NSNumberFormatter.